# Inline-block and line-height rendering differently on Chrome, Safari and Firefox

Tags: html, rendering, css

I style `code` tags as follows:

```
 code {
   display: inline-block;
   white-space: no-wrap;
   background: #fff;
   font-size: .8em;
   line-height: 1.5em;
   color: #555;
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
   -webkit-border-radius: 0.4em;
   -moz-border-radius: 0.4em;
   -ms-border-radius: 0.4em;
   -o-border-radius: 0.4em;
   border-radius: 0.4em;
   padding: 0 .3em;
   margin: -1px 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-clip: padding-box;
   -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
 }
```

and here is how it renders on

- Safari (correct)
  [image]
- Chrome (incorrectly aligned)
  [image]
- Firefox (incorrectly aligned)
  [image]

I find it strange especially that Chrome and Safari are rendering differently. What can be done here to bring the vertical alignment back to the same baseline as the normal text?

Comment: Have you tried `vertical-align:middle`?

Comment: Yes. When I do this, Chrome and Firefox work, but Safari renders too low: http://cloud.coneybeare.net/S9LQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can also use `vertical-align: middle;` instead of line-height.

Comment: When I do this, Chrome and Firefox work, but Safari renders too low: cloud.coneybeare.net/S9LQ

Comment: try using display table-cell instead of inline-block;

Comment: table-cell forces a new line

Comment: here is a live example: http://matt.coneybeare.me/how-to-make-an-html-signature-in-apple-mail-for-mavericks-os-x-10-dot-9/

Comment: While it didn't fix the problem, it made it better as the slightly lower Safari render is better and affects fewer viewers than the chrome massive alignment fail

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the same issue, but I recently found that on `display: inline-block` elements, using `line-height` causes Safari and Chrome to align things differently.
In my situation adding `vertical-align: middle` causes them to at least align things the same way, allowing me to use line-height to then position things correctly.